# CiviCRM 5.31.0 Wordpress unable to change default language

Tags: sql, language, l10n

I currently have CiviCRM 5.31.0 for Wordpress installed. I want to change the default language from EN_US to Dutch (NL). After a quick google i found a tutorial and did the following steps:

1. Downloaded to 5.31.0 language zip file
2. Uploaded all l10 and sql files to the correct folder
3. logged into wordpress and navigated to the 'administer' == 'localization' ==> 'Language & currency' page
4. I changed to default language to Dutch, turn 'Inherit CMS Language' on (Wordpress is also in Dutch) and hit save.
5. It loads, throws me back to the dashboard screen of CiviCRM and nothing translated...

I also tried translating the plugin using Loco Translate yet the translation file found by loco translate only contains 20 strings and not all text.

What am i doing wrong? Did i miss something?

Can someone maybe explain why it just ignores my save and keeps everything en-us? Is there a way to force CiviCRM to take a specific language or something?

Please let me know.

Kind regards,

Max

Comment: Can you check php log if there are any errors?

Comment: If you originally install in english, then some words will still be in english even after you change the language because of the way civi lets you change many dropdown choices. You can use https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/fixoptiontranslations to "fix" those. But it sounds like nothing is translating so it might be different problem.

Comment: @Demerit Thnx for the quick response, I've double checked and some parts are translated and other parts aren't. Very strange... The "Fixoptiontranslations" extention seems to work well so i'll try to manually translate all remaining texts. 

Ps. Is there no possibility to automate this process? (Just out curiosity)

Comment: If you initially install in Dutch then it's automatic. You would download the language zip file before installation, and then on the installer page you have a choice. But once you've installed it can't be automatic since then it might overwrite the words people have customized.